# Как собрать bundle.min.js с помощью webpack

Tags: javascript, плагин, webpack2, минификация

Пытался сделать минификацию `.js` с помощью `UglifyJsPlugin`, однако, плагин выдает вот такую ошибку:

> Unexpected tocken: punc (.) [bundle.min.js:1,10]

Если заглянуть в этот файл, то оказывается, что `.min` добавляется к названию переменной в первой строке, что приводит к ошибке, но как этого избежать я не пойму: `var bundle.min = /* some code */`

Конфиг:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {

    entry: {
        "bundle": './app/intWid',
        "bundle.min": './app/intWid',
    },

    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: '[name].js',
        library: '[name]'
    },

    module: {

        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                use: [{
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: { presets: ['es2015'] }
                }]
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            include: /.js$/,
            minimize: true
        })
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        include: /\.min\.js$/,
        minimize: true
    })
]
```

В `include` просто нужно правильно описать минификацию